# Servlet request blocking

Tags: java, http, servlets, servlet-filters

I have a Filter which scans all the request going through my application. I want to block a request if it requests for a specific url. I can able to check this and if the condition matches I am NOT doing chain.doFilter, but still the request moves to a black page. How can I block this request from going any further and stay in the current page - meaning user should not see any change to the screen that he clicked?

Answer (score 2):

The HTTP [status code 204](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) might work, but it is not guaranteed to work with all browsers:

> 204 No Content
>
> The server has fulfilled the request
>   but does not need to return an
>   entity-body, and might want to return
>   updated metainformation. The response
>   MAY include new or updated
>   metainformation in the form of
>   entity-headers, which if present
>   SHOULD be associated with the
>   requested variant.
>
> If the client is a user agent, it
>   SHOULD NOT change its document view
>   from that which caused the request to
>   be sent. This response is primarily
>   intended to allow input for actions to
>   take place without causing a change to
>   the user agent's active document view,
>   although any new or updated
>   metainformation SHOULD be applied to
>   the document currently in the user
>   agent's active view.
>
> The 204 response MUST NOT include a
>   message-body, and thus is always
>   terminated by the first empty line
>   after the header fields.

(emphasis mine)

Alternatively, you can try one of these strategies:

1. Have the servlet return 307 (temporary redirect) back to the previous page using the HTTP Referer field. This approach might cause problems with caches and proxies.
2. Use ajax to load contents from your servlet. You will have to substitute direct links with JavaScript calls that initiate ajax calls to substitute part of your page. The URL in the browser will not change when you load contents this way, which may or may not be desirable. Many sites use a mix, including StackOverflow. Anything that should be "permalink-able" is navigated to via a regular link, but parts of each page is fetched lazily via ajax.

Finally, what's wrong with telling the user a link is off limits? Have the servlet return 403 (forbidden).

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The browser has already made the request and it's out of its hands. You might be able to hack something where you return a little bit of javascript that silently "hits" the browsers "back" button, but that no doubt has all sorts of nasty issues with it.

But once the browser is has sent the request, the current page is "dead".